# How to set text color using <drawable name="foo">#ffAABBCC</drawable>

Tags: android

In my colors.xml file I have the following color: `<drawable name="my_favorite_color">#ffFF0000</drawable>`. How can I programmatically set the color of a TextView to this value? In other words, what goes in here?

`myTextView.setTextColor(???);`

Note that there is no R.color.my_favorite_color so `myTextView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.my_favorite_color));` does not work. There is only R.drawable.my_favorite_color. In a layout file, I can do this: `<TextView android:textColor="@drawable/my_favorite_color"/>` Is that impossible in code?

Answer (score 1):

first define color in color.xml in res/value

`<color name="my_favorite_color">#ffFF0000</color>`

then get it

`myTextView.setTextColor(R.color.my_favorite_color)`

Answer (score 0):

```
myTextView.setTextColor(R.color.my_favorite_color);
```

Answer (score 0):

`myTextView.setTextColor(R.color.my_favorite_color)`

You've defined your color wrongfully. It should be under a file called 'colors.xml' and be like

`<color name="y_favorite_color">#ffFF0000</color>`

Comment: There is no R.color.my_favorite_color but only R.drawable.my_favorite_color

Comment: <drawable> doesn't define a color, <color> does

Comment: In a layout file, I can do this: <TextView android:textColor="@drawable/my_favorite_color"/> Is that impossible in code?

Answer (score 0):

Its Simple you can set the color to your myTextView:

```
myTextView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.my_favorite_color));
```

Comment: There is no R.color.my_favorite_color but only R.drawable.my_favorite_color

Comment: No ,I think we can't apply like that,
 if you ask about background it will possible i.e myTextView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.my_favorite_color);